# Shipping Address in Magento 2 logged in customer on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

[image]

form where this coming . this is login customer shipping address

Answer (score 0):

These addresses come from Customer Account.[image]

Comment: on code level where i can see

Comment: what exactly you want to see in code? Do you want js component which renders these items on the checkout page?

Comment: yes i want to check zip code

Answer (score 0):

This is the `html` file from where these addresses are rendered

> $.Magento_Root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

And if this file is overridden then it must be in

> /app/design/frontend/Your_Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

Answer (score 0):

**Listing of Shipping addresses**

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/list.html
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js
```

To locate the shipping address, the below file will be helpful

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html
```

This file will be responsible to render all address attributes

i.e. starting from the **firstname** to **telephone** covering all.
Zipcode will also rendering here.

```
<text args="address().postcode"/>
```

JSComponent responsible for address renderer

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js
```

To extending or overriding content, require to add corresponding file in your theme folder. `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>`